# Kafka with mTLS Authentication and RBAC Authorization

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, rbac

I have just completed the setup of a secure [Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/overview.html) Kafka cluster locally in **KRaft mode** using **mutual TLS Authentication** (same CA) and now I am wondering how to proceed with the **Authorization** part.

The cluster is deployed using a Docker-Compose file with the following images:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka
- https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
- https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest

Based on the documentation to me it's not clear if this is a commercial feature, if I need to add other services (MetaData Service, OAuth, LDAP) which I'd prefer to avoid, or if it is just a matter of configuration for the existing services.

- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/authorization-overview.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/rbac/index.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/configure-mds/mutual-tls-auth-rbac.html
- https://developer.confluent.io/courses/cloud-security/rbac-and-acls/

[Here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/security/rbac/docs/index.html) they also talk about using a Hash Login service instead of LDAP. It seems to be just a file with the users & password hashes:

```
# HashLoginService Initializer
confluent.metadata.server.authentication.method=BEARER
confluent.metadata.server.user.store=FILE
confluent.metadata.server.user.store.file.path=/tmp/login.properties
```

Considering that I just want to authorize the CN of the certificates (probably about 100) to read/write from/to certain topics, what is the quickest and easiest way to set up RBAC authorization?

Comment: To answer my first doubt, based on https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/rbac/index.html#rbac-implementation-checklist and https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/license.html#enterprise-subscription-license, the RBAC feature requires an Enterprise (Subscription) License.